# Subquery to Calculate Average Distance w/limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a selection procedure that relies on creating two intermediate tables. I need help rewriting the code to use subqueries rather than intermediate tables.

I really don't understand subqueries and every one I've tried returns an error.

This code provides the result I want but relies on creating intermediate tables:

```
Select modded_vgi_ptsutm.pplx,ST_Distance(modded_vgi_ptsutm.geom,split_polygons.geom) as dist into intermediate from modded_vgi_ptsutm,split_polygons where split_polygons.objectid = 87 order by dist as limit 10;

Select pplx,count(pplx) as count,avg(dist) as dist into intermediate2 from intermediate group by pplx order by dist asc;

Select pplx,dist from intermediate2 where count > 1;
```

Note: I posted this to here rather than the gis page because I think my particular problem is more sql than gis

Comment: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll definitely work through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use subqueries to combine these:

```
Select pplx, avg(dist) as dist
into intermediate2
from (Select modded_vgi_ptsutm.pplx, ST_Distance(modded_vgi_ptsutm.geom, split_polygons.geom) as dist
      from modded_vgi_ptsutm cross join
           split_polygons
      where split_polygons.objectid = 87
      order by dist
      limit 10
     ) t
group by pplx
having count(pplx) > 1
order by dist;
```

Note:  the use of the comma in the `from` clause is suspicious, because it results in a cartesian product.  I replaced it with an explicit `cross join`.

Comment: +1 for pure speed - I was still understanding the SQL! :P But yeah, seems to be doing what it should!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT pplx,dist FROM 
    (
    SELECT pplx,count(pplx) AS count,avg(dist) AS dist FROM 
        (
        SELECT modded_vgi_ptsutm.pplx,ST_Distance(modded_vgi_ptsutm.geom,split_polygons.geom) AS dist FROM 
        modded_vgi_ptsutm,split_polygons where split_polygons.objectid = 87 ORDER BY dist AS LIMIT 10
        ) 
    GROUP BY pplx ORDER BY dist asc
    ) 
WHERE count > 1;
```